# Auto-Fullscreen with javascript (FS button click)

Tags: javascript, html, css, code-snippets

I have a camera system that is casted to a tv using chrome. The page loads initially with a banner and in small view and I want the page to open in fullscreen by default (the cameras timeout after so long and the page must be refreshed at an interval)

I've wrote up a quick snippet to automate the process of going fullscreen using similar to the code below

```
/* Fx for click action */
function simulateClick(control){
    if(document.all){
        control.click()
    }else{
        var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evObj.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 12, 345, 7, 220, false, false, true, false, 0, null );
        control.dispatchEvent(evObj)
    }
}

/* Doc Element to be acted on */
var FSToggle_ELEM = "Icon-module_icon__2a0I8 Icon-module_icon-medium__2_Qyn Icon-module_icon-light__27kpC";

FSToggle_ELEM = document.getElementsByClassName( FSToggle_ELEM )[2];

/* Execution */
simulateClick( FSToggle_ELEM )
```

Note: This works in console but not as a snippet

It should be noted that the webpage for the cameras has a banner on the left/top of the page, by pressing fn+F11 the banner remains; 
by clicking the aforementioned button it goes fullscreen and removes the banner.

Running the code in the console works as expected; however, when ran as a snippet, I get the error that Fullscreen API: ... fullscreen must be made by a user gesture.

This there anyway to accomplish this effect with a snippet?

Or would it be easier to circumvent the problem entirely and just re-style the page entirely so that the banner is no longer visible and the videos are scaled for FS as opposed to trying to do it with automating the click event?

Note #2: The banner is part of the app (not the chrome window itself)

Comment: No, you can't. Fullscreen must be triggered by users event. This is a limitation, otherwise all kinds of ads and tracking scripts would be able to trigger fullscreen as well, and nobody wants this.

Comment: Meaning it is advisable to just restyle the page using JS so that it's in "fullscreen" appearance?

Comment: You can make a button "go fullscreen" for your users, it depends. This isn't much useful, because users just have to press F11 or similar in mobile. But if you want some javascript code to go fullscreen with a button, i will make an answer.

Comment: I have resigned myself to that workaround; however, that doesn't explain why the code I wrote works in console (using JS to click the native fullscreen button) ((as though it were a user gesture)) and doesn't as a snippet ((as though it's different from running through the console?))